# Using rewind in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Is it possible to rewind when you press a designated key in opencv? I have got the below but it does not rewind the playback.

```
def run(self, filepath, fps, width, height, monochrome=False):

    video_file = self.read_file(filepath)
    previous_frame = None


    while (video_file.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = video_file.read()

        if previous_frame is not None:
            pass

        previous_frame = frame

        if ret:

            frame = self.color(frame, monochrome)

            final_frame = self.resolution(frame, width, height)

            delaytime = self.frame_per_second(fps)


            cv2.imshow('frame', final_frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(delaytime)

            if key & 0xFF == ord("p"):
                cv2.waitKey(234320)
                if key & 0xFF == ord("r"):
                    cv2.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES(2, previous_frame))


    video_file.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The above code takes it to the previous frame but does not play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal solution is to set the frame number that needs to played when the video is paused to achieve the rewind effect. This can be done through [video capture properties](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set):

> **cv2.VideoCapture.set(propId, value)**
>
> *CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES* 0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next.

Helpful examples are available at "[Jumping between frames in video files](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781788474443/1/ch01lvl1sec24/jumping-between-frames-in-video-files)".

This is a **source code example** that pauses the video and provides some control to let you rewind to the previous frame or jump to frame zero and restart the video:

```
import cv2
import sys

# load input video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('TheMandalorian.mkv')
if (cap.isOpened() == False):
    print("!!! Failed cap.isOpened()")
    sys.exit(-1)

# retrieve the total number of frames
frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

# loop to read every frame of the video
while (cap.isOpened()):

    # capture a frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("!!! Failed cap.read()")
        break

    cv2.imshow('video', frame)

    # check if 'p' was pressed and wait for a 'b' press
    key = cv2.waitKey(int(frame_count/1000))
    if (key & 0xFF == ord('p')):

        # sleep here until a valid key is pressed
        while (True):
            key = cv2.waitKey(0)

            # check if 'p' is pressed and resume playing
            if (key & 0xFF == ord('p')):
                break

            # check if 'b' is pressed and rewind video to the previous frame, but do not play
            if (key & 0xFF == ord('b')):
                cur_frame_number = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
                print('* At frame #' + str(cur_frame_number))

                prev_frame = cur_frame_number
                if (cur_frame_number > 1):
                    prev_frame -= 1

                print('* Rewind to frame #' + str(prev_frame))
                cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, prev_frame)

            # check if 'r' is pressed and rewind video to frame 0, then resume playing
            if (key & 0xFF == ord('r')):
                cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
                break

    # exit when 'q' is pressed to quit
    elif (key & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        break

# release resources
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Key press options:

- Press `q` to exit the application.
- Press `p` to pause.
- When paused, press `p` again to resume playing.
- When paused, press `b` to rewind a single frame. You must press `p` to resume playing again.
- When paused, press `r` to rewind back to frame 0 and automatically resume playing.

Comment: Hey. I tried to do that but as you can see, I assigned 'p' to pause the video. When the video is paused and I try to press 'b' to go back a frame it just starts playing again. I don't think the 'b' is working. Somehow unable to get that effect. What do you think about having that 'if' loop in another 'if'? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I think you might be missing an extra `waitKey()` to capture the `b` key press.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the previous frame, it is possible to store in a temporary array. 
For example:

```
prev_frame = curr_image.copy()
```